# Private channel between AWS China and Global AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, rds

I have a project with Web part on both areas (EU and China) and i have two account on both AWS (Global and AWS China).

Can i make private channel between Chinese Zone and any Zone in Global AWS (for example Signapore) for replication of DB/Sync data and other issues.

I need something like that private channel because ping and connect between that zones via public DNS almost already bad. 
Maybe someone have some experience with some architecture like this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note in most cases this works poorly for China because VPNs generally are not stable across the GFW interface; you can stay up for a while but IPSEC, etc. are not stable.  Some companies can do cross-connects such as Aryaka and CBC, and of course MPLS - expect $1-3K/month to start.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would use an official third party connection with DirectConnect to connect Singapore with one of the AWS China regions. I know China Mobile International can do this.